# How can I validate multiple files first and add the rest of the form data to the database only if they're valid?

Tags: php, sql, validation, file-upload

I'm not very experienced in coding PHP and MySQL, and am therefore looking for help. I'd like to do the following:
I have a form where users enter their contact details and at the end of the form there is a multiple file upload button.
Now if they submit the form, the following should happen:
First, I wanna check if all of the uploaded files are valid (file types are ok), if this is true, then the contact details should be entered to table_X of db_Z.
Then, all files should be moved/uploaded to the server and in table_Y of db_Z the file name, the (let's call it) eventID and date and time of the upload should be inserted, whereas the eventID is a foreignkey of the ID of the entry of the contact details.

The code I have until now is close, but the final step is missing. It adds the contact details to the database regardless of the result of the validation of the files.

How can I change it, so that it only adds something to the database if all files are valid? And also that it adds the contact details only once to database regardless of how many files are being uploaded?

Thanks in advance

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $obs_fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname');
    $obs_lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname');
    $obs_address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'adresse');

    // Include the database configuration file
    include_once 'dbConfig.php';

        $query = "INSERT INTO bear (obs_fname, obs_lname, obs_address)
        values ('$obs_fname','$obs_lname','$obs_address')";

          $result=$db->query($query);
          // verify results
          if(!$result) {
            $message  = "ERROR SAVING POST : ".$db->error . "\n";
            $db->close();
            echo ($message);
            return false;
          }

    /**
    * get the last inster id of the Post
    **/
       $post_id = $db->insert_id;
       echo "Post id=".$post_id ."<br>\n";

       // File upload configuration
       $targetDir = "uploads/";
       $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

       if(isset($_FILES['files'])) {
           foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $name) {
               $image_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];

               move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, './uploads/' . $name);
    /**
    * now insert the image with the post_id
    **/
       $query = "INSERT INTO images (eventID, file_name, uploaded_on)
       VALUES ('$post_id', '$name', NOW())";

                         $result=$db->query($query);
         // verify results
         if(!$result) {
           $message  = "ERROR INSERT IMAGE : ".$db->error . "\n";
           $db->close();
           echo ($message);
           return false;
         }
           }
       }
       header("Location: upload-complete.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the MIME type on the server-side using [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) or using an image function that will return `FALSE` if it is not an image such [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

you gonna need a function like this + you need to validate the size `$_FILES['files]['size]` and the file extension `$file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION))`

```
function validate_images($image_tmp){

 foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $name) { // you need the tmp_name here and not "name" name is the one was when the file was in the client computer, After the form sent, the file will be in `/tmp` on the server and that is where php is accessing it.
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    if(strpos(mime_content_type($image_tmp),"image")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(validate_images($image_tmp)){
    // do the rest
}else{
    die("no no no");
}
```

Also look here [w3school image upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)